# T-SQL Query Performance Improvement

Tags: sql, performance, linq, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This query takes around 30 seconds to compile. Plus since this is written in `LINQ` so the load time is even more.

I am planning to move this into a stored procedure. Please guide as to which are the areas I can focus upon and improve the performance of the query.

I have a query... somewhat like this.

```
SELECT Table2.[Column1] AS [Column1]
    ,Table2.[Column2] AS [Column2]
    ,[Table7].[Column3] AS [Column3]
    ,Table2.[Column4] AS [Column4]
    ,......around 15 colums more selected
FROM (
    SELECT Table1.[Column1] AS [Column1]
        ,Table1.[Column2] AS [Column2]
        ,Table1.[Column3] AS [Column3]
        ,Table1.[Column4] AS [Column4]
        ,......around 10 colums more selected
    FROM (
        SELECT Table3.[Column1] AS [Column1]
            ,Table3.[Column2] AS [Column2]
            ,Table3.[Column3] AS [Column3]
            ,Table3.[Column4] AS [Column4]
            ,......around 10 colums more selected
        FROM [dbo].[Table3] AS Table3
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table5] AS Table5 ON Table3.[Id] = Table5.[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table4] AS Table4 ON Table5.[Id] = Table4.[Id] AS Table1
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table6] AS [Table6] ON Table1.[Id] = [Table6].[Id]
        ) AS Table2
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1) [Table8].[Column1] AS [Column1]
        FROM (
            SELECT Table2.[Column1] AS [Column1]
                ,[Table9].[Column2] AS [Column2]
            FROM [dbo].[Table9] AS [Table9]
            WHERE ([Table9].[Id] = Table2.[Id])
                AND ('tableName' = [Table9].[TableName])
                AND ('columnName' = [Table9].[ColumnName])
                AND ([Table9].[LanguagCode] = @p__linq__0)
            ) AS [Table8]
        ORDER BY [Table8].[Coulmn2] ASC
         AS [Table7]
    )
```

Comment: Without having the context on what you're trying to do, it's almost impossible to say.  My first instinct is to pull apart the nested `FROM (SELECT` and try to get as many basic table references instead of subqueries.  Subqueries, while sometimes necessary, can frequently be a source of lost time (mainly in WHERE clauses but still).  Also, just from a straight readability standpoint, the WHERE being entirely subqueries is a nightmare.

Comment: Can you post what you are trying to do?  The LINQ code could be helpful in doing this.  Trying to untangle the mess that LINQ creates will be nearly impossible.  If we know what you are trying to really do, we can probably create something far simpler than that monstrosity.

Comment: context is...reduce the execution time time of the above query. Like one point as you said - try to remove the nested `FROM(SELECT`. What other things can improve the performance? Can you write a sample query of how it will look like?

Comment: @Becuzz, I am moving the `LINQ` query into a `Store Proc`. The above query is the RAW SQL query that the LINQ query created.

Comment: I am looking for ideas to implement. I know there is no proper answer to my question. But helpful advise will matter.

Comment: I understand that.  If you can show the LINQ, I can probably tell you the best way to make that a stored proc.  The SQL that LINQ makes is always horrible.  It is much easier to go from the LINQ to good SQL than from that horribad query to good SQL.

Comment: @Becuzz, i will have to get back to you on that.

Comment: It looks like something is missing near `Table4.[Id] AS Table1` and again near `AS [Table7]`

Answer (score 0):

I would start by storing each of the subqueries in a temporary table with a relevant index. For example Table2 can be refactored like this. This should improve performance.

```
INSERT INTO #table2
SELECT Table3.[Column1] AS [Column1]
        ,Table3.[Column2] AS [Column2]
        ,Table3.[Column3] AS [Column3]
        ,Table3.[Column4] AS [Column4]
        ,......around 10 colums more selected
    FROM [dbo].[Table3] AS Table3
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table5] AS Table5 ON Table3.[Id] = Table5.[Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table4] AS Table4 ON Table5.[Id] = Table4.[Id] AS Table1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table6] AS [Table6] ON Table1.[Id] = [Table6].[Id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 3 sub-queries you can make it in one query itself. Instead of Outer apply you can use left join. You can write ur query something like below.

```html
SELECT Table3.[Column1] AS [Column1]
            ,Table3.[Column2] AS [Column2]
            ,Table3.[Column3] AS [Column3]
            ,Table3.[Column4] AS [Column4]
            ,......around 10 colums more selected
        FROM [dbo].[Table3] AS Table3
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table5] AS Table5 ON Table3.[Id] = Table5.[Id]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table4] AS Table4 ON Table5.[Id] = Table4.[Id] AS Table1
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table6] AS [Table6] ON Table1.[Id] = [Table6].[Id]
  Left Outer join [dbo].[Table9] AS [Table9] ON [Table9].[Id] = Table3.[Id]
      AND ('tableName' = [Table9].[TableName])
      AND ('columnName' = [Table9].[ColumnName])
      AND ([Table9].[LanguagCode] = @p__linq__0)
```

But please make sure that both the queries is giving you the same output before moving ahead. Let me know if this is helpful to you.

Thanks,
Sarat